# Difference in numpy indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Why this indexing result in different arrays?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(range(0,2*3*4)).reshape(2,3,4)

print(x[0,:,[2,3]])
print(x[0,:,2:])
```

the first output is

```
[[ 2  6 10]
 [ 3  7 11]]
```

the second one is

```
[[ 2  3]
 [ 6  7]
 [10 11]]
```

in the second case `2:` means take from the 2nd value until the end, the last column of that dim is the 3 column, that means that it is taking the 2nd and 3rd dimensions, therefore that is the same as [2,3], so what is the difference between both ways of indexing arrays?

Comment: In the first case the sliced dimension is put last, because of the particular mix of advanced and basic indexing.  Some argue that this is a borderline case, and shouldn't behave like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are different for indexing with an array (or a list) of integers and for slicing. This is explained in-depth in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), in particular in the part on [mixing advanced and basic indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing).

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, `x[0,:,[2,3]]` implies that `numpy` will return an array such that `x[0,:,2]` is the first item followed by `x[0,:,3]`. In the second case, `x[0,:,2:]` you are asking `numpy` for 2nd and 3rd column of the 0th matrix.

The indexing documentation is available [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html).